# Changing the fill color of an SVG on rollover using 'this'

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a map of 50 states in which each state is an SVG and placed on an HTML canvas.

I would like to change the fill color when a user rolls over the state. I could do this with CSS, but that's a lot of individual classes/ids. In the interest of efficiency, I would like to run javascript functions that change the fill color of each state as each state is rolled in and out of.

I can't get the simple script to work. Here is what I have:

```
         function hoverColor() {
             this.style.fill = 'red';
         }

         function regularColor() {
             this.style.fill = 'yellow';
         }
```

I can see my onmouseover="hoverColor" and onmouseout="regularColor" are triggering the function call in the Chrome console.

Edit: Here's a simplified version of code:

```
<svg width="400" height="110">
  <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" onclick="changeColor" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

and the javascript:

```
function changeColor() {
  this.style.fill = "rgb(255,0,0)";
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how would you like to be answered if you also give a little information? PLEASE READ : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: you must prove that you are calling your functions correctly, for example, but you may also have made a thousand other errors...

Comment: If you are creating the states as a class of objects, every state with it's d attribute, you may also create a new path and probably set the d attribute for the path. In this case you need to change the fill color of the path. So instead of `this.style.fill` you may need `this.path.style.fill`. If this is not what you need please edit your question and add a simplified version of your code

Comment: @mister-jojo You're correct - I apologize for the snark. 
Here is an example: https://codepen.io/blur/pen/jOWLQvR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inline eventhandler attributes need function call syntax

```
onmouseover="hoverColor(evt)" onmouseout="regularColor(evt)"
```

And the functions can use the event parameter

```js
function hoverColor(e) {
  e.target.style.fill = "red"
}

function regularColor(e) {
  e.target.style.fill = "yellow"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I do appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I feel like you are discovering the use of SVG on a web page.
here is what I recommend:

```js
function hoverColor() {
  this.style.fill = "red"
}

function regularColor() {
  this.style.fill = "yellow"
}

const svgRect = document.querySelector('#svg-rect')

svgRect.addEventListener('mouseover', hoverColor)
svgRect.addEventListener('mouseout', regularColor)
```

```css
#my-svg {
  width: 200px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  }
#svg-rect {
  fill:rgb(0,0,255);
  stroke-width:3;
  stroke:rgb(0,0,0)
  }
```

```html
<svg id="my-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 200">
  <rect id="svg-rect" x="50" y="40" width="300" height="100" />
</svg>
```